# FabricJS Clipboard implementation (Copy/Paste)

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I am having an issue regarding my implementation of a clipboard in fabricjs. When I clone groups, the boundingBox/Controls are in the correct position, but the objects get thrown in the top left corner of the Canvas and I can only move the controls.

Here is my implementation so far:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c");
var clipboard = null;

function Copy() {
    // Single Object
    if(canvas.getActiveObject()) {
        // Does this object require an async clone?
        if(!fabric.util.getKlass(canvas.getActiveObject().type).async) {
            clipboard = canvas.getActiveObject().clone();
        } else {
            canvas.getActiveObject().clone(function(clone) {
                clipboard= clone;
            });
        }
    }

    // Group of Objects (all groups require async clone)
    if(canvas.getActiveGroup()) {
        canvas.getActiveGroup().clone(function(clone) {
            clipboard = clone;
        });
    }
}


function Paste() {
    // Do we have an object in our clipboard?
    if(clipboard) {
        // Lets see if we need to clone async 
        if(!fabric.util.getKlass(clipboard.type).async) {
            var obj = clipboard.clone();
            obj.setTop(obj.top += 10);
            obj.setLeft(obj.left += 10);            
            canvas.add(obj);
            // We do not need to clone async, all groups require async clone
            canvas.setActiveObject(obj);
            clipboard = obj;
        }  else {
            clipboard.clone(function(clone) {
                clone.setTop(clone.top += 10);
                clone.setLeft(clone.left += 10);
                canvas.add(clone);

                // We need to clone async, but this doesnt mean its a group
                if(clipboard.isType("group")) {
                    canvas.setActiveGroup(clone);
                } else {
                    canvas.setActiveObject(clone);
                }
                clipboard = clone;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My implementation of these methods and my logic might be redundant and their possible is a better, smaller, more efficient way of doing this (please let me know).

I am not sure if this is a bug or me doing something wrong. Keep in mind that I don't know what objects might be cloned, which is why I need to know if I need to use asynchronous clone or not and this is only way I found how to do it.

**UPDATE:** Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mk9egte7/) of the issue (group the objects and copy/paste)

Comment: Did you fix the problem?? I'm not facing any issue in your fiddle as you specified.

Comment: @JayadrathaMondal whenever I try to paste a group I copied everything breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its looks like problem is in the setActiveGroup function. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mk9egte7/5/). In line number 49 & 54 I wrote console.log(). See result in console, you can see that _objects property length is 0. That means there has no object in the group. Now just remove the setActiveGroup function. Now _objects property length is 2.

I don't know if it is normal or have any bug in setActiveGroup function.
But then I tried adding group objects manually in canvas, instead of adding full group at a time. I have replaced your fiddle line 48 with below.

```
clone.forEachObject(function(obj){
    canvas.add(obj);
});

canvas.deactivateAll();
```

Now it worked. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mk9egte7/4/).

And yes for safety use canvas.deactivateAll() if you want to manually set active group or object. You can also use canvas.discardActiveGroup() or canvas.discardActiveObject() according to your requirements.

I think we cant add cloned group directly to the canvas. Instead we have to add each objects of that group individually. Please someone else confirm.

Comment: This is a good answer, but I will submit a bug report to see exactly if this is a bug or not, thanks!

Comment: @HunterMitchell yes you should do it. I also want to see if it is really a bug or not.

Comment: @HunterMitchell Did you ever determine if this is a bug or not? Working out my own copy/paste implementation and running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem recently; the reason why clone objects get thrown out of the canvas is when you calculate the left of the object to be cloned, you get the left position inside the group not the canvas. To get the canvas related left of object here is how it works for me

```
var cloneGroup = canvas.getActiveGroup();
if (cloneGroup) {
            var objectsInGroup = cloneGroup.getObjects();
            objectsInGroup.forEach(function (object) {
                var cloneobj = object.clone();
                cloneobj.set({
                    left: ((object.left + object.group.left )+20),// added 20 to add some gap
                    top: ((object.top + object.group.top) + 20),
                    width: object.get('width'),
                    height: object.get('height'),
                });
                canvas.add(cloneobj);
            });
        }
 canvas.renderAll();
```